# MVC component SelectList bug - wrong width when initialized inside hidden div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hidden, selectlist

I have this stupid problem with SelectList initialization

In my view I'm initializing a list:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label">Offer type</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Filter.OfferTypeList, 
        new SelectList(Model.OfferTypes, "IdOfferType", "Name"), 
        new { multiple = "multiple", size = "1", @class = "form-control multipleSelect" })
</div>
```

When the list initializes, everything is OK. The SelectList's width is through half of the screen.

I'd like to use some collapsing - it means, that on page init, this div is wrapped inside a div with style="display:none;"
But that causes MVC to set width of the SelectList to 100px; which is not intended.
You can simply simulate this by initialising a SelectList inside hidden div and then removing the display:none with FireBug - puff, too small!

EDIT: I forgot to mention, we are using bootstrap 3

Thanks for suggestions, maybe the solution is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net MVC doesn't add any additional styles if you are not setting it directly.
So the problem is in the default size of the select elements on HTML page.
Please see this [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Y60Fc)
I set the style for `select` input

```
select { width: 200px; }
```

So all `select` elements on the page would have width = 200px by default.
To set fixed size of your select you should set style for `multipleSelect` class.

Comment: It is the MVC-generated (I think) div, which has the wrong width:
    <div class="ms-parent" style="width: 100px;" > ...
Hmm, but I just found out, that there's also jquery.multiple.select.js tampering with this...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap try to adjust the `<div class = "col-md-6">`

Bootstrap divides the main div in 12 parts.

For more info follow the link : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Hope it helps

Comment: Tried that, the size of the column doesn't matter.
I didn't post the whole code, The first column is also col-md-6.
But thanx for suggestion.